# Ember.JS - Return & Display Parameter from URL

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm building my first Ember app and I'm trying to get it to pass and display a parameter in the view, grabbing it from the URL...

So basically if someone went to index.html#/quotes/5
I want the view to display "TEST: 5"

**App.js:**

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('quote', function(){
    this.resource('quoteNumber', {path: ':quote_id'});
  });
});

App.quoteNumberRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return(params.quote_id);
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="quote">
      Test: {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="quoteNumber">
      {{quote_id}}
  </script>
```

so if I go to "example.com/index.html#/quote/3"
I'd simply want the view to display "TEST: 3",
if I went to "example.com/index.html#/quote/10"
I'd want the view to display "TEST: 10"

but right now it displays nothing, and I can't find what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the use of `quote_id` in the template.  Inside the template you are telling handlebars to grab the property `quote_id` off the model provided for that template.

Dissecting the model associated with that route you'll see that the model itself is the `quote_id` value, `5` or `7` etc.  The model that would fit your template would be `{ quote_id: 5 }` that way Ember/Handlebars can search for the property `quote_id` on the model and bind to that value.

Here's an example of what you're trying to do (note, I could have just returned the params object itself).

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/309/edit

I also added a convenient link, but you could type in any url and get what you were desiring, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/309#/quote/123123

PS. You didn't show, nor mention, but you also need an application template.  This is the root of your application, if you plan on having nothing in it, you can just put a `{{outlet}}`

Ex.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

or for short

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm now :)
out of curiosity why do you use quote_id twice in quote_id:params.quote_id?